# Can't authenticate to Google Container Registry using JSON key file from within GCR

Tags: docker, google-compute-engine, google-container-registry

I [believe I] have setup the tooling and configuration similarly between my local system and the build systems.

I can run this, successfully, locally:

```
$ cat key.json | docker login -u _json_key --password-stdin https://us.gcr.io
WARNING! Your password will be stored unencrypted in /home/local/MAGICLEAP/doprea/.docker/config.json.
Configure a credential helper to remove this warning. See
https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/login/#credentials-store

Login Succeeded
```

..but the same command fails from the job, which is running in GCE:

```
cat key.json | docker login -u _json_key --password-stdin https://us.gcr.io
error getting credentials - err: exit status 1, out: `docker-credential-gcr/helper: could not retrieve GCR's access token: metadata: GCE metadata "instance/service-accounts/default/token?scopes=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fcloud-platform" not defined`
```

It seems to really want to find the token in the instance metadata rather than just using the file that I'm giving it.

I could use some advice.

Answer (score 0):

There may be an issue with your “.docker/config.json” file, you can compare the “config.json” between your local system and the build systems.

Running the following commands in your the build system to verify status and config file of docker, please make sure that “docker-credential-gcr” is installed before troubleshooting.

$ docker -v

$ docker-credential-gcr configure-docker

$ cat ~/.docker/config.json

$ docker login -u oauth2accesstoken -p "$(gcloud auth print-access-token)" https://us.gcr.io

I recommend these topics [“Pushing and pulling images”](https://cloud.google.com/container-registry/docs/pushing-and-pulling) and [“Authentication methods”](https://cloud.google.com/container-registry/docs/advanced-authentication#before_you_begin) for troubleshooting.

Comment: Yes. I had duplicated my local config to the remote system, and it still didn't work. Yes. I've been through those pages.

Comment: This works in my test environment, I edited the forth command for testing and troubleshooting, and also suggest you to update and re-initial the Google Cloud SDK, https://cloud.google.com/sdk/docs/#install_the_latest_cloud_sdk_version
You may need system administrator permission "sudo" to run the commands.

Comment: This specifically bypasses the problem that I am reporting. We *do not* have our key in the metadata. It's in a physically file. Even when we pass it in, we get the error about it not being found in the metadata.

Comment: Dose this command "docker login -u _json_key --password-stdin https://us.gcr.io < key.json" work on your side ? And this topic may works for your issue. https://medium.com/infrastructure-adventures/docker-registry-login-with-google-cloud-service-accounts-6bd528bed134

Comment: It's functionally identical to the original command in the question, so the result is the same.

Comment: According to the error message, there is a possibility the default service-accounts of instance miss "cloud-platform" scope, please try these steps to change the "access scopes" of instance from “Allow default access” to “Allow full access to all Cloud APIs”:
Log into Google Cloud Console, navigation menu ⇒ compute engine ⇒ click VM instance ⇒  click ”Stop” and then click “Edit” ⇒ find “Access scopes” and select “Allow full access to all Cloud APIs” ⇒ Save.
Start VM instance and try to test again.

Comment: It's a moot point. We do not and will not push these keys into the metadata. Again, it shouldn't even be checking **if we're giving it a key**.

Comment: As I know that pull or push Docker images to Google Container Registry without GCloud Shell tool, your default service account or custom service account has to get correct permissions. You download the service account JSON key to your local or remote system for authentication. I followed this topic "https://medium.com/infrastructure-adventures/docker-registry-login-with-google-cloud-service-accounts-6bd528bed134" to reproduce your issue in my testing environment, and the command  “docker login -u _json_key --password-stdin https://us.gcr.io  < key.json” was working without error.